# Fetch error trying connect with php in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try conect with my php file, i have a error with "res.json()" my console say "Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at FormCorreo.js:20" but I cant see the error

```
import React from 'react';

//Envio de correo  (Ventana 3)

class FormCorreo extends React.Component{

    enviar(){
        let data = document.getElementById("correo").value;
        console.log(data);
        fetch("http://localhost/proyectos/send_mail.php",{
              method: 'POST',
              body: JSON.stringify(data),
              headers:{
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
               },
               mode: 'no-cors'
          })
          .then(res => res.json())
          .then(resJson => console.log('good: ' + resJson))
          .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
          .then(response => console.log('Success:', response));
     }


    handleFormSubmit( e ) {


    }

    render(){

        return(
            <span className="form-correo">

                <input type="email"  name="correo" id="correo"  placeholder="email@email.com"/>
                <button id="correobtn" value="Submit" onClick={e => this.enviar()} >ENVIAR POR CORREO</button>
                <div id="contenido_php"></div>
            </span>
        );
    }
}

export default FormCorreo;
```

Comment: can u post ur PHP response

Comment: Now it´s a a simple echo <?php 

    echo "Hello PHP"


?> @sarvonks

Comment: you need to send a response in **json format**, otherwise `res.json()` will throw an exception

Comment: you got response as text but you trying to convert to json. its not possible.  kindly change `res.json()` to `res.text()`

Comment: @sarvonks exactly now a dont have error, but "res" its empty what i do to look text?

Comment: @javierpartidamolina then remove `.then(res => res.json())` and remove `resJson` arguments

Comment: its look like `fetch("http://localhost/proyectos/send_mail.php",{...}).then(resJson => console.log('good: ')).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))`